# Spring mvc file upload

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm working on spring mvc file upload. in the view, i use plupload multiple file upload plugin. here is my upload action:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = CrudURI.uploadDo, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String uploadDo(@RequestBody MultipartFile file, 
        @RequestParam String name, 
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="-1") int chunks,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="-1") int chunk) {


    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/uploads/"+name)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    } else {

    }

    System.err.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
    return null;

}
```

this action is working without any error or exception, but the uploaded file not saved. what's the problem?
thanks

Comment: Your code is correct. Just check full directory path and check that file exists there. Can you print absolutePath of your file and see if it exists there?

Comment: excuse me, what exactly you mean?

Comment: My question where exactly "uploads" directory is? are you getting uploads directory created where you are expecting it to be?

Comment: You are right. problem is the file path. i found the uploaded files in the bin folder of tomcat server. i need to move file after saving it. thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117703/how-to-upload-image-with-spring-mvc-i-try-this-way-how-to-fix-this help me, fix this spring mvc file handling issue, please

Answer (score 1):

Simply try following code:

```
File fileToSave=new File("/uploads/"+name);
file.transferTo(fileToSave);
```

And also make sure that you are actually getting file in mapping.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually getting the file? Or actually the mapping you did is working?

Comment: yes, i tested ` file.getOriginalFilename()` and this get me a file name. this means the file sends to server correctly,right?

Comment: Yes and are you sure that you are checking at the place with right name for image?

Answer (score 0):

Darshan solution is correct, your original code has an issue that you're reading a file as *getBytes()* which is not using a buffer, but your writing using a buffer.

I think that your issue is most likely that you're trying to overwrite the uploaded file, at least it appears so based on your output location `"/uploads/"+name`. Try changing the name, and instead of having an empty catch block, add log for your exception it will point you to the issue